# AngularJs : How can i access contorller scope variable into directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am making real time d3 visualization chart but can't access controller scope into directive.

```
var app = angular.module('myChart', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

app.controller('chartCtrl', function($scope, $http, $mdDialog, $window){

// Get chart setting
$http.get('chart_setting.php').then(function(res){
    $scope.info = res.data;
    $scope.me = 'hello';
});

});

app.directive('motionChart', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    scope: {info: "="}
}

function link(scope, el, attr){
    console.log(scope.info);// Here is info data in json 
    console.log(scope.me);// Try to fetch simple string but not success
}

});
```

In the directive, i need "info" and "me" scope variable. but can't access.

If i console scope then data llook like

[print whole scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wem90.png)

Scope print successfully but when i get scope.anyVariable i get undefine.

Thanks

Comment: It's a while since I've done AngularJS, but I'm guessing you might need scope: {info: "=", me: "="} in the directive.

Comment: Tried but no success...it fine work in template but not in link :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<motion-chart info="info"></motion-chart>

app.directive('motionChart', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    scope: {info: "="}
}

function link(scope, el, attr){
    var dataWatch = scope.$watch("info", function(n,o){
        if(n) init();
    });

    scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
        dataWatch(); //stops watching
    });

    function init(){
        console.log(scope.info); //gives value of info
        console.log(scope.$parent.me); //gives controller $scope.me value
    }
}

});
```